# Get all the image shots from dibbbler API

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I am trying to learn react-native, I just start working on this project two days ago. 
I have kind of confusing in how to get the all the image shots from [dibbbler API](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/shots/) and display it on my android emulator.

[image: here is the error]

This is what I have done,

```
'use strict';
 import React, {
 AppRegistry,
 Component,
 Image,
 ListView,
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 } from 'react-native';


 var API_URL = 'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots';


 class myproject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 this.state = {
 dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  }),
  loaded: false,
};
}


 componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
      }

      fetchData() {
        fetch(API_URL)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            this.setState({
              dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.images.treaser),
              loaded: true,
            });
          })
          .done();
      }

      render() {


        return (
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.rendershots}
            style={styles.listView}
          />
        );
      }



      rendershots(shots) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: shots.images.treas}}
              style={styles.images.treas}
            />

          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      rightContainer: {
        flex: 1,
      },

      treas: {
        width: 53,
        height: 81,
      },
      listView: {
        paddingTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('myproject', () => myproject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide credentials to retrieve the pictures from dribble.

You can register your app [here](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/) to get credentials then use them to use the Dribbble API.